Registering the container itself with Autofac does not work in ASP.NET Web API on .NET 4.7.2
The following does not work for me:
IContainer container;
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
container = builder.Build();
builder.RegisterInstance(container).As<IContainer>();

One of my controller require a instance of IContainer but this approach does not work for me.

You're registering a container with the builder, but you're not re-building it. Can I ask why you want to do this? The only reason I can think of is to create lifetime scopes elsewhere. Otherwise, IComponentContext should be all you need in factories, etc.

Adding to my previous comment: you don't want to add the container and then rebuild it, since you'll end up with two containers. I should have made that point clear. I was just trying to explain why you're not seeing it in your existing container.

Register a delegate, not the object.
IContainer container = null;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(ctx => container).As<IContainer>();
container = builder.Build();

A hint, though - if your controller takes an ILifetimeScope instead of IContainer, the Autofac injection will automatically inject the current lifetime scope. So if you need to resolve something using service location, inject ILifetimeScope in your constructor instead of IContainer. Then you don't have to register anything.

Thank you very much. In my case, I needed an ILifetimeScope in my constructor instead of an IContainer.
